# What are the modified and untracked files?

Tags: visual-studio-code

In VS Code, on the left side, is a file tree.
Some files are marked "M" and most are marked "U".
How do I change the files from "M" to "U" or vice-versa?
Which is correct or the norm?

[image: File tree]

Comment: it is the git/SCM status of the file, Modified, Untracked, as soon as you commit a file it will never be an Untracked file, unless you you remove the (git) tracking of a file

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to '*brush up*' on [Using Version Control in VS Code, Git support](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/versioncontrol#_git-support).

> Visual Studio Code has integrated source control management (SCM) and includes Git support out-of-the-box.

> **Note:** If you are new to Git, the [git-scm website](https://git-scm.com/documentation) is a good place to start

Comment: Thank you both. Now I have to learn about Git